How to use tmux display-message -p on login without entering copy mode?
When I use display-message -p in my .bashrc, the messages it creates forces tmux to enter copy mode.
How to send a message to stdout when tmux starts, without using tmux send keys, and without starting copy mode?
I want to make the display-message -p work as an echo when tmux starts up, echoing the message into the terminal without starting copy mode.
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  # Check if any tmux sessions exist
  if tmux ls 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null; then
    # when this message is printed, it is only shown in copy mode
    tmux attach-session \; display-message -p "attached to session"
  else
    # when this message is printed, it is only shown in copy mode
    tmux new-session \; display-message -p "new session"
  fi
else
  # this is the only message that goes to the terminal's stdout without activating tmux copy mode
  tmux display-message -p "already in a session"
fi

These are the logs, the display-message sent to /dev/pts/0 is shown in copy mode, but the display-message sent to /dev/pts/1 is shown in the terminal's stdout.
Why are the display-message commands sent to different pseudo terminals?
17:25: /dev/pts/1 command: show-messages
17:25: /dev/pts/0 key C-c: send-keys -X cancel
17:25: /dev/pts/1 command: display-message -p "already in a session"
17:25: /dev/pts/0 command: display-message -p "new session"
17:25: /dev/pts/0 command: new-session

Somehow only this one sent to /dev/pts/1 shows up in the terminal stdout without entering copy  mode /dev/pts/1 command: display-message -p "already in a session"

where do u want the message to show up?

In the terminal but not in the status bar. Just as an echo, but not an echo that causes copy mode to activate

say a vim session is running in the tmux pane, then where do u want the message to show up?

Thank you @pynexj that is an excellent point! I didn't consider that scenario. I want to make it fall back as a regular display-message if an interactive program such as vim or a tui is running.
